# How to override devise lockable module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I tried to override Lockable module to support in devise-token-auth but it is not overriding. I searched on everywhere and found nothing. I think I missed something but I don't know what. Any help would be appreciated

```
module Lockable extends Devise::Models::Lockable

  def valid_for_authentication?
    # My code 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop that `extends` and include the module in your devise model (User, is it?)

```
module MyLockable
  def valid_for_authentication? # or whatever
    ...
  end
end

class User
  include MyLockable
end
```

Or you can simply define that method in the user directly.

```
class User
  def valid_for_authentication?
    ...
  end
end
```