# Rails5 API + devise_token_auth edit token format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, reset-password, devise-token-auth

so i'm using devise_token_auth gem for basic user functionalities, and I made some simple changes to the reset password flow. Basically instead of having a link in the email for the user to click and go to the reset page, I show the token, so the users has to copy it and enter manually in a field.

It is working like that, but the token is to large and ugly, i'd like it to be something like 6 alphanumeric digits. It looks better and it makes things easier for the user. I don't quite know how to do it, I probably should overwrite some devise original Controller. How to do it? As devise_token_auth places a controller "on top" of every original devise controller and what I want is to overwrite the set_reset_password_token from devise's recoverable module.

EDIT: I've found the answer myself so i'll answer it below! But please, feel free to complain, ask and propose better/alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of, if you want to overwrite a function from a devise module, you can just write it with the same name on your model file, probably in models/user.rb. For overwriting the set_reset_password from recoverable module, you can just do the following (as suggested by [Sergio Tulentsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125816/sergio-tulentsev) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214659/how-to-override-devise-lockable-module)):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable
  ...

  protected
    def set_reset_password_token
      ...
    end
end
```

Now for changing to how you want your raw token to be (before it's encrypted), in my case I wanted it to have 6 digits, containing only A-Z, a-z, 0-9 digits, lets see what devise does ([link to github file](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb)):

```
def set_reset_password_token
  raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(self.class, :reset_password_token)

  self.reset_password_token   = enc
  self.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
  save(validate: false)
  raw
end
```

What `Devise.token_generator.generate` ([seen here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/TokenGenerator)) does is generate a raw token using `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(rlength).tr('lIO0', 'sxyz')` (of length 20, [as seen here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise#friendly_token-class_method)) and return the raw and encrypted token unless some user already has the same token assigned.

Finally, what you need to do is rewrite this set_password_token using [SecureRandom](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) functions allied with [tr](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr) to generate tokens any way you like, and don't forget to make sure the token is unique and not currently being used.